# Play AVAudioPlayer when device volume is zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I am playing an audio using AVAudioPlayer in my app.

```
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
[self.audioPlayer play];
```

Is it possible to play the audio with sound even when device volume has been reduced to zero from control center popping up from bottom?

I have seen "[Sleep Cycle](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/sleep-cycle-alarm-clock/id320606217?mt=8)" app playing musics independent of device volume.

Please advice,

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default behaviour of silent mode using an audio session. This is how you would activate it:

```
NSError *error = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&error];
```

To deactivate and rollback to the default (like when you stop)

```
NSError *error = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:&error];
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrea, i will try this today and get back to you. :-)

Comment: No, it is not overriding iPhone's volume.